# How to update a table with sum of values from two other tables in MySQL

Tags: mysql, sql

I have three tables created in MySQL. As shown below
**Ap2**
With fields *StudentID* and *Total_Score*

**Term3**
With fields *StudentID* and *Total_Score*

**Term4**
With fields *StudentID* and *Total_Score*

I am trying to SUM(Total_Score) in ***Term3*** and add it to the SUM(Total_Score) in **Term4** and update the Total_Score in ap2 with the sum of Term3.Total_Score and Term4.Total_Score. i.e ap2.Total_Score = Term3.Total_Score + Term4.Total_Score. I have tried to achieve this with the code below but MySQL is saying 0 rows affected, even though the SQL statement gives no errors. I need assistance as to what I should do. See my code below.

```
UPDATE ap2 AS c
LEFT JOIN (
SELECT StudentID, SUM(Total_Score) AS TotalScoret3
FROM term3
GROUP BY StudentID
) AS p ON c.StudentID = p.StudentID
LEFT JOIN (
SELECT StudentID, SUM(Total_Score) AS TotalScoret4
FROM term4
GROUP BY StudentID
) AS l ON c.StudentID = l.StudentID
SET Total_Score = COALESCE(TotalScoret3, 0) + COALESCE(TotalScoret4, 0)
```

Comment: Check if you're allowed to update the table without selecting a row

Comment: Do not store in table names, data that should be stored in a table column

Comment: The update statement looks correct to me. I would qualify the columns, though: `SET c.Total_Score = COALESCE(p.TotalScoret3, 0) + COALESCE(l.TotalScoret4, 0)`.

Comment: If not rows are affected, then the subqueries are returning `0` or no rows or `apc` has no rows.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suspect you need to insert the rows, rather than `update` them.  For this, you can use `on duplicate key` with an `insert`:

```
INSERT INTO ap2 (studentid, total_score)
    SELECT StudentID, SUM(Total_Score)
    FROM ((SELECT StudentID, Total_Score
           FROM term3
          ) UNION ALL
          (SELECT StudentID, Total_Score
           FROM term4
          ) 
         ) t
    GROUP BY StudentID
    ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE total_score = VALUES(total_score);
```

Note that the most recent versions of MySQL prefer a somewhat different syntax, but this will work for a while.

For this to work, you need `ap2(studentId)` needs to be the primary key or defined to be unique:

```
alter table ap2 add constraint unq_ap2_studentid unique(studentId);
```

Comment: Thank you @Gordon_Linoff. Your answer worked. You are right. I actually needed an insert, not an update.

Answer (score 0):

As I understand the task you need in:

```sql
REPLACE INTO Ap2 (StudentID, Total_Score)
SELECT StudentID, SUM(Total_Score)
FROM (SELECT StudentID, Total_Score
      FROM Term3 
      UNION ALL
      SELECT StudentID, Total_Score
      FROM Term4) subquery
GROUP BY StudentID;
```

https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=b13bec3b139f137c3143c067ff27a4d8

`Ap2(StudentID)` must be unique (maybe, primary key).